# SQL to provide characteristics mandatory for each entity

Tags: sql

I need a SQL for the following requirement.

Table A:

```
Product      Charactersitic      Value
A                Age              100
A                Number           100
B                Age              100
```

Table B:

```
Charactersitic
Age 
Number
```

Output Should be:

```
Product      Charactersitic      Value
A                Age              100
A                Number           100
B                Age              100
**B                Number           Null**
```

This means each characteristic is Mandatory for each Product.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `cross join` and a `left join`:

```
select p.product,
    c.characteristic,
    p2.value
from (
    select distinct product
    from products
    ) p
cross join characteristics c
left join products p2 on p2.product = p.product
    and p2.characteristic = c.characteristic;
```

`CROSS JOIN` produces every single possible combination of product and characteristic and then you can `LEFT JOIN` the products with the result of the cross join to get the desired result.

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/ZGU43341)

Comment: Thanks. I have not tested it but I think it will work.